# Line style and x_jitter for seaborn factor plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Seaborn factor plots are fantastic but how do I influence line style (e.g. dashed etc for better b/w readability). And how do I apply "x_jitter" so the different confidence intervals don't occlude each other?
Thanks!

Here is an example that does not have those changes applied.

```
>>> import seaborn as sns
>>> sns.set(style="ticks")
>>> exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")
>>> g = sns.factorplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", data=exercise)
```

Comment: See the third and fourth examples [here](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn-dev/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html)

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot!

Comment: Link doesn't work anymore

Comment: http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.factorplot.html

Answer (score 1):

*Brief explanation to make sure that the complete solution is included, not just the links.*

`sns.factorplot` forwards additional arguments to the underlying plotting function. In your example, `sns.pointplot` is used to plot the data and you can pass the arguments `linewidths` and `dodge` to this function:

```
sns.factorplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", data=exercise, dodge=0.2, linestyles='dashed')
```

[image]